# Google map is producing null pointer exception while getting nearby places

Tags: java, android, google-maps

i want to fetch nearby places using google map but i m getting null pointer exception. I m using this function

```
   public void onClick()
    {
        Object[] dataTransfer = new Object[2];
        GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
                String url = getUrls(latitude, longitude, search_place);
                dataTransfer[0] = mMap;
                dataTransfer[1] = url;

                getNearbyPlacesData.execute(dataTransfer);
                Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Showing Nearby " +search_place, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
private String getUrls(double latitudes , double longitudes , String nearbyPlace)
{

    StringBuilder googlePlaceUrl = new 
    StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    googlePlaceUrl.append("location="+latitudes+","+longitudes);
    googlePlaceUrl.append("&radius="+PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
    googlePlaceUrl.append("&type="+nearbyPlace);
    googlePlaceUrl.append("&sensor=true");
    googlePlaceUrl.append("&key="+"MY_API_KEY");

    Log.d("MapActivity", "url = "+googlePlaceUrl.toString());

    return googlePlaceUrl.toString();
}
```

Now the null pointer is occcuring here

```
private void showNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlaceList)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < nearbyPlaceList.size(); i++)
        {
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = nearbyPlaceList.get(i);

            String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
            String vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity");
            double lat = Double.parseDouble( googlePlace.get("lat"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble( googlePlace.get("lng"));

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng( lat, lng);
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(placeName + " : "+ vicinity);
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));

            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions); // Here is the null pointer
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));
        }
    }
```

In above function when i saw the url the value of latitude and longitude is always 0.0 thats why it might be zero 
I watched many tutorials but latitude and longitude values are never assigned

This is my error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: `mMap` is null, but there's not enough information here for us to be able to tell you how to fix it, specifically.

Comment: @MikeM. i need a further help.. u were right that mMap was null but now when i fetch nearby places ,they are wrong .. for  example if i want to see restaurants... map shows me different other places.. Can u help me to getting accurate nearby places

Comment: is `nearbyPlace` the string `restaurant`? If so, the API should only return restaurant places. Please can you share the full nearby search request you're making and the results you're getting that are unexpected for you?